# Data isn't inserted to database - python

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql

I want to add some data to database using python, but I have a problem. The data to one table is successfully inserted but the problem is with the other table.

There are two tables `vehicles` and `vehicle_price` as follows:

[image]
[image]

My code is as follows:

```
def insert_vehicles_to_db(vehicle):
    conn = db_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    if vehicle_not_exists(vehicle, conn, cur):
        try:
            insert_vehicle(vehicle, conn, cur)
            insert_vehicle_price(vehicle, conn, cur)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
    conn.close()
```

Function `insert_vehicle` is as follows:

```
def insert_vehicle(vehicle, conn, cur):
    try:
        query = "INSERT INTO vehicles (reference, data, price, reference_url, timestamp) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
        cur.execute(query, (vehicle['reference'], "", vehicle['price'], vehicle['reference_url'], datetime.datetime.now()))
        conn.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

That works fine, the vehicles are always inserted. But the problem is in the next one, in `insert_vehicle_price` which looks as follows:

```
def insert_vehicle_price(vehicle, conn, cur):
    try:
        vehicle_data = get_vehicles(vehicle['reference'], vehicle['reference_url'], conn, cur)[0]  # get the last vehicle
        vehicle_id = vehicle_data[0]
        vehicle_price = Decimal(vehicle['price'] + ".00")

        query = "INSERT INTO vehicle_price (price, timestamp, vehicle_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"
        cur.execute(query, (vehicle_price, datetime.datetime.now(), vehicle_id))
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Thus for some reason the prices aren't inserted.

Any idea why?

**UPDATE**

The function `get_vehicles` looks as follows:

```
def get_vehicles(reference, reference_url, conn, cur):
    try:
        sql_get_vehicles = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE reference = %s and reference_url = %s"
        cur.execute(sql_get_vehicles, (reference, reference_url))
        return cur.fetchall()
    except Exception as e:
        # TODO Handle error
        pdb.set_trace()
        pass
```

Comment: Don't catch the exception and ignore it. The exception might give a hint what's going on.

Comment: @Matthias I tried to add `pdb.set_trace()` in every exception, but I haven't seen anything. I've removed it from my question for simplicity.

Comment: Just remove your exception handling. Do you get an error now?

Comment: I do not get any errors, with or without exception. The data in insert_vehicle is inserted but the data in insert_vehicle_price isn't inserted.

Comment: You have a problem with your **get_vehicle** function, can you show it?

Comment: @nacho I updated my question. But the values that I get from that function are correct.